# lightning input type = date, max attribute behaviour not similar in production and lower enviornment

Tags: lightning-web-components, validation, date, lightninginput, max

I used max attribute of lightning input type date to disable the future dates in date picker.
It was working in lower environments, but not working in production.

In Lower Environments:
It shows the dates in disbaled format, user cannot select the date.

[image]

In Production Environment:
It shows the dates in disabled format, but user can select the date and then error message is displayed.

To verify same , I went in playground , there also it is allowing user to select the dates even though dates are being greyed out.

[image]

Does anybody know anything about this, is it a salesforce known issue.